# Using Intel IPP to decompress a lossless JPEG

Tags: jpeg, lossless-compression, intel-ipp

I am trying to decompress the following lossless JPEG bitstream (ITU 81):

- http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/thingies/intel_ipp_lossless.jpg

It seems to have been generated by:

```
$ strings -n 20 intel_ipp_lossless.jpg 
4Intel(R) IPP JPEG encoder [5.3.497] - Aug 12 2008
```

Which is compatible with:

- https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-integrated-performance-primitives/topic/282884

> IPP JPEG supportsfollowing compression modes defined by JPEG ISO/IEC
>   10918:
>
> 1. Baseline, 8-bits, DCT based process, huffman entropy coding
> 2. Extended baseline, 8- and 12-bits, DCT based process, huffman entropy coding
> 3. Lossless, 1..16 bits, prediction based, huffman entropy coding

But I am having a hard time understanding how to use IPP:

- https://software.seek.intel.com/performance-libraries

  - -> Intel® Integrated Performance Primitives

When I look at the examples I cannot find anything related to JPEG decompression anymore.

Where/How can I use IPP JPEG decoder ?

---

Update: Seems like intel ipp forum is not very active anymore.

- https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-integrated-performance-primitives/topic/809600

Comment: In searching around, I found that IPP no longer supports JPEG encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is poorly documented, but some function (in particular the JPEG codec) has been removed. So you need to use the Legacy IPP library from:

- [Intel® IPP Legacy Libraries](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp-legacy-libraries)

With documentation at:

- [How to Build Intel® IPP Legacy Samples with Intel IPP 9.0 Legacy Libraries](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-build-former-intel-ipp-samples-with-ipp-90-legacy-libraries)

The difficult part is that the sample tar file is not accessible for new user as mentionned here:

- https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-integrated-performance-primitives/topic/585171

So I'll need to write my own JPEG decoder based of the following forum post (`ippiDecodeHuffmanOne_JPEG_1u16s_C1` reference):

- https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-integrated-performance-primitives/topic/304947

---

Update: instead one should search for ipp samples such as `w_ipp-samples_p_7.1.1.013.zip` (or  `ipp-samples.8.0.0.005`) on internet to have access to the JPEG compressor/decompressor.